# Strong password overlay on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I faced with strange overlay on `UITextField`. I'm using field of type `textContentType = .password` and `isSecureTextEntry = true`. I have also eye button to unhide password characters with changing `isSecureTextEntry = false`.

When I do that my password characters are visible, but when I type at least one new character **Strong password** overlay appears and it's no way to hide it.

What is that and how to prevent to show it?

[image: strong password overlay]

// EDIT:

I've made extension to disable AutoFill and it's works:

```
extension UITextField {
    func disableAutoFill() {
        if #available(iOS 12, *) {
            textContentType = .oneTimeCode
        } else {
            textContentType = .init(rawValue: "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is one of Autofill features. I found same view on this web page: https://medium.com/developerinsider/ios12-password-autofill-automatic-strong-password-and-security-code-autofill-6e7db8da1810

Comment: I think this is because of password autofill feature of iOS please try below code to get rid of it `if #available(iOS 12, *) {
    // iOS 12 & 13: Not the best solution, but it works.
    passwordTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
} else {
    // iOS 11: Disables the autofill accessory view. 
    // For more information see the explanation below.
    emailTextField.textContentType = .init(rawValue: "")
    passwordTextField.textContentType = .init(rawValue: "")
}`

Comment: User would be able to cancel autofill, please can you test again, there would be a way for the user of the app to cancel autofill and manually fill it.

Comment: this is not working for me iphone 6s ios 13.5

Comment: But this will stop autofill to work. For me I just want to avoid that yellow 'strong password' overlay.

Answer (score 11):

Found the only solution for this problem.

```
textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

Otherwise iOS 12 uses PasswordAutofill for any secure field (textField.isSecureTextEntry = true).

This solution is from apple developer forum [Yuri Petukhov](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/108085)' answer.

Comment: This just turns the field into a one-time-code field. Like a 6 digit code texted to the user. So yes.. This does fix it visually. But it's not really a password field anymore as far as auto fill is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cause the text to be revealed to the user, which isn't ideal IMO.

To solve this:

Set the content type of the password field to: .oneTimePad, set secure text entry on the field to:  false, and then add following (or whatever flavor works for you):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { 
    if(textField == self.passwordTextField) { self.passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true } }
```

Side Note - I tried to put that ^ change in the viewWillAppear, but the ugly yellow box still shows up.

This was the only way I found to keep the text secured/hidden initially ( you can then toggle it with a show/hide button if you want and the autocomplete nonsense from Apple doesn't come back)

Answer (score 0):

Credit Christian Diaz for the answer: This seems to be a bug with using secure text field on iOS simulators with version 14.0 and up. I would suggest using the simulator with version 13.7, the one right before 14.0. If you don't see the option to choose devices with 13.7, click on:

Xcode -> Preferences -> Components -> iOS 13.7 Simulator

This will install iOS 13.7 simulators for devices before the iPhone 12.

Just make sure you see 13.7 on your simulator's top bar.

Comment: This still isn't fixed in iOS 16.2...