# UITextField textContentType .password acting like .newPassword for no apparent reason

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Has anyone run across an issue where `UITextField`.`textContentType` of `.password` acts like `.newPassword` for no apparent reason?

I've inherited an app with a bad UX in the sign in flow, which is: the password field is suggesting an unwanted strong password, when focused on.

The interface has a `UITextField` with the `textContentType` set to `.password`, not `.newPassword`.

[image]

I have also tried the each of the solutions ([from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952151/strong-password-overlay-on-uitextfield)):

- Setting the content type to `.oneTimeCode` (and others like `.unspecified`), which do get rid of the suggestion, but have the undesirable side effect of: altering the keyboard accessory view to not show the keychain/password manager button.
- I have the other less desirable solution, of setting `isSecureEntry` to false in the UI, and then programmatically changing it in a delegate method, which does not do the trick either. (Well, it *kind of* does... It works correctly for the **first** focus, then subsequent focuses, the password suggestion is back).
- My app has dependencies that don't build for the simulator (this is happening on a real device), so it's not a simulator bug.

The object is `UITextField` in both the interface builder and the code, so there are no subclassing issues going on. And I've looked at every extension in the project, none of which touch the `textContentType` or `isSecureEntry` properties.

I've also debugged the UITextField during runtime, and ensured that no other code is changing the `textContentType` property to `.newPassword` unexpectedly; it's not. At the time I see the issue, the value *is* still `.password`.

In terms of the code, the *only* thing a little unusual to me, is how the `delegate` is set:

```
@IBOutlet var _passwordTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        _passwordTextField.delegate = self
        
    }
}
```

But changing this to be in the Interface Builder had no effect.

I've tried removing/changing the delegate methods (below), also with zero effect:

```
extension LoginViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {     
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField === _emailTextField {
            _passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField === _passwordTextField {
            _passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            if self.isInputValid {
                login()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text,
           let textRange = Range(range, in: text) else {
            return true
        }

        var valid = false
        let updatedText =
         String(text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string))
        if textField === _emailTextField {
            valid = updatedText.isValidEmail && !(_passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true)
        } else if textField === _passwordTextField {
            valid = (_emailTextField.text?.isValidEmail ?? false) && !updatedText.isEmpty
        }
        _loginButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = valid
        return true
    }
    
}
```

There is no other code that makes any sort of assignments to that object. Every reference is reading from the `.text` property (to check if it's valid, and prepare and http request).

Also, the deployment target is `iOS 14.0`, if that matters.

This seems like such an easy thing to fix, but I have been looking for hours to find a solution, any I cannot. I'm really at a loss here. Any ideas?

Comment: `replacingCharacters(in` already returns a `String`. Initializing a new string from its result is pointless

Comment: Leo, I assume the original developer did that, because `updatedText` is used in multiple places, to keep the code more dry & readable. However, no changes I ever made to delegate methods actually addressed the issue I'm experiencing. I just added this code for reference, so anyone with questions about what the delegate methods are doing, could be them